# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587; java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Tags: java, exception, servlets, smtp, jakarta-mail

I tried a lot of tutorials to create an app for email sending, but every code throws the same error:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail {

public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String host ="smtp.gmail.com" ;
        String user = "myEmail@gmail.com";
        String pass = "myPassword";
        String to = "receiverEmail@gmail.com";
        String from = "myEmail@gmail.com";
        String subject = "My first email";
        String messageText = "Some text";
        boolean sessionDebug = false;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        //java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject); msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(messageText);

       Transport transport=mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
       transport.connect(host, user, pass);
       transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
       transport.close();
       System.out.println("message send successfully");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}}
```

Do I maybe need to install additional software, or something else?

**UPDATE:**

The problem is somewhere in my wireless router.

I used mobile (3G) internet via hotspot on my mobile phone and everything worked great.

Now we could solve the problem if somebody has experience with router setup.

Comment: Seems you can't get reached the google mail server, can you `ping smtp.gmail.com`  from your computer?

Comment: may be firewall on the client machine blocking outgoing calls or somewhere at the other end. Detail can be found here, https://coderanch.com/t/476146/java/SMTP-Send-Email-Java-Mail

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand well, what do you mean by 'ping smtp.gmail.com' ?

Comment: Ohh i understand now. I tried the command, and here is th result:
`ping smtp.gmail.com
PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (74.125.133.108) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wo-in-f108.1e100.net (74.125.133.108): icmp_seq=1 ttl=41 time=56.5 ms
--- gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 24034ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 55.846/72.355/100.889/11.747 ms`

Comment: The problem is somewhere in my wireless router.

I used mobile (3G) internet via hotspot on my mobile phone and everything worked great.

Now we could solve the problem if somebody has experience with router setup.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a firewall blocking outgoing calls. The firewall could be either on the clientside or on the server.

Comment: and what could I do to avoid that? I tried this command `ping smtp.gmail.com `, and got this result:
`PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (74.125.133.108) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from wo-in-f108.1e100.net (74.125.133.108): icmp_seq=1 ttl=41 time=56.5 ms --- gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com ping statistics --- 25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 24034ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 55.846/72.355/100.889/11.747 ms`

Comment: The problem is somewhere in my wireless router.

I used mobile (3G) internet via hotspot on my mobile phone and everything worked great.

Now we could solve the problem if somebody has experience with router setup.

Comment: What router?  All routers are different.  Did you set up the router yourself?  It's unlikely you set up a firewall "accidentally".  Are you sure you don't have firewall or anti-virus software on your computer that is blocking the access?  The JavaMail FAQ has [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

Comment: I use Ubuntu so that I do not need some special anti-virus software. And as I told, if I connect to the internet via 3G internet, it works, and if I do it via my wireless router, ti doesn't work. I got the router from my internet provider, so maybe they blocked something. Thanks Bill for your advices, I'll take a look at the JavaMail FAQ link

Answer (score 0):

May be your google app authorization for third party is off ,so try by allowing them:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: The problem is somewhere in my wireless router.

I used mobile (3G) internet via hotspot on my mobile phone and everything worked great.

Now we could solve the problem if somebody has experience with router setup.